# Call a function in the PowerShell Terminal Window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i writed this simple function in visual studio code:

```
def example(x):
    for i in range(0,x):
       print(i)
```

and the code runs in the visual studio editor, but when a i try to call the function in the terminal:

```
example(11)
```

The output is the following error:

```
The term 'example' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or 
executable program. 
Check if you typed the name correctly, or, if you included a path, check that the path is 
correct and  try again.
Inline: 1 Character: 1
+ example(11)
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (example:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Powershell is not Python. A function defined in one doesn't somehow become available in the other. You could probably call `python.exe so-python-file.py` from Powershell instead.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is not a python editor. You need to enter Python first so that you can call the Python interpreter and write the code.

[image]